# GITLAB pull and push code requiring my Gitlab account

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab

[When I try to pull or push my code to remote repo always have this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWg1E.png)

How can I set my account login automatically? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you used SSH authentication.

- Generate an SSH key
- Upload your public key to Gitlab -> Person Settings -> SSH Keys
- You can delete your local copy and pull it again using SSH or change the remote origin to the SSH URL

You can find [more info here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)